# Xcode 4 project opens, then hides folders

Tags: xcode4

I just upgraded to Xcode 4, and I'm trying to open a project I created with the previous Xcode, but when I open it, after about 1 second, it hides all the folders and inline projects in the project navigator, and only shows the "resources" folder. Strange behavior. I can compile and run, but I can't edit my files from xcode any more.

Anyone else see this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why it fixed, but it did. After closing down xcode and restarting several times, it ended up working ok again. Strange

Comment: yep...same thing with me. very strange, but it seems a lot of solutions are the same with xCode

Comment: @CoolDocMan's answer works for me, The XCode UI preserves that pick even when you close the project so closing and re-opening does not alleviate the situation.

Answer (score 3):

@haider I had the same issue with XCode 4.3, tried the above recipe, but it did not work for me. Here is the correct answer to prevent this from happening and get it to work right:

There's a tiny row of icons to the left of the search box under the left hand nav. The first of these is a '+' (to add a file). The icons following the add-a-file icon are actually filters that can be toggled on and off. The first of these looks like a clock, and is a filter to show only-recently-modified files, the second to show files-with-source-control status and so on. I must have accidentally picked the first icon after the '+' (show only recently-modified files) and therefore had the problem. The XCode UI preserves that pick even when you close the project so closing and re-opening does not alleviate the situation.